# How to setup linting for not called function typos in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, function, lint

I noticed I sometimes miss function call brackets when writing a code.

I mean:

```
function someFn(): void {
  Date.parse;   // - instead of Date.parse(date)
  JSON.stringify;  // -- instead of JSON.stringify({})
  doSomething;  // -- instead of doSomething()
}
```

I'd like my IDE notice it becouse this kind of typos are really hard to debug in big projects.

Is there any way to lint such situations with TypeScript, ESLint etc.?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions - for other cases i can think of, TS should either show you it's the wrong type, or the second version is completely valid.

Comment: I mean situations when function is writen as a expression and I forget about () to invoke it. It's not possible to use types for solve this issue.

Comment: It should be, unless the function's type is a subtype of its return type.

Comment: I've updated my question to better explain what i mean.

Comment: Any why exactly do you believe the eslint rule i suggested in the first comment wouldn't catch this? Note, that even `Date.parse(date);` as an expression statement is useless (no side-effects, return discarded), but that's hard for a linter/type-checker to understand - analyzing semantics of code gets very hard very fast.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. I don't know why I didn't understand before.